# How to pass variable when adding a cartridge?

Tags: openshift

I am building a cartridge and I can't figure out how to pass variables when a user adds the cartridge.

More specifically, the cartridge I am building requires the user's API key to run. So I need the user to pass an API key when he tries to install the cartridge. How should I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using rhc env set and using an environment variable?

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. I think it would be good to mention this in the main documentation in the Env variable section...

Answer (score 1):

This post shows how to use Environment variables with some additional application/quickstart source code in order to add support for an external Redis database provider: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-get-easy-access-to-hosted-redis-with-redis-cloud

You can use the same pattern to bootstrap any application with some initial keys, right from the command line.

If you set these variables after your initial app creation step, then you may need to reload your app in order to read the new keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them as parameters when creating your app.

```
rhc app create YOUR_APP_NAME URL_TO_MANIFEST \
  --env VARIABLE1=foo \
  --env VARIABLE2=bar
```